# Disabling a particular package inside app/java folder in android studio

Tags: android, package, android-studio-2.3

I'm not sure if this is possible in Android Studio. But how can i disable a particular package that i made inside the app/java folder?

[image]

I want to disable my dagger package because i want to make a new one for experimental purposes. But i don't want to delete the previous package so i still have a reference (for viewing purposes only).

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use version control? Just make new branch for testing with new content of dagger package and clean everything there. You will have master branch with original content of that package and created branch with empty package for experiments.